# PowerShell GUI Output

Tags: powershell, user-interface, ping

I'm writing a small PowerShell script, with GUI, that processes the Ping command. Currently I have the script reading input from the user to determine the IP Address / URL to ping, and then displaying the output to a rich-text-box.

However, currently, the command COMPLETES then writes the entire output at once. I want it to display each line of output in real time - so that it appears the same way that it would running the command in the shell.

When the Ping button is pushed, the following function is called (and I think this is where the issue is):

```
Function FNPing {
    $OutputBox.Text = "Please Wait..."
    $ping = ping ($InputBox.text)
    $OutputBox.Text = ""
    foreach ($line in $ping) {
        $OutputBox.Appendtext($line+[char]13+[char]10)
    }
}
```

I imagine that the issue can probably be solved in the ForEach statement, I'm just not aware of how to do it! All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would try using the `test-connection` cmdlet. The problem is that ping an external exe so all you are getting out of it is a blob of text when it completes. The only way to get the output of ping while it is running is going to be by using `start-process` and redirecting the output (this is quite messy).

With `test-connection` you won't get a pretty summary but the info is all there. For the summary info, `measure-object` can help. Here's an imitation of ping's output that should get you started:

```
function fnping {
    $outputBox.Text = "Please Wait..."
    $count = 4
    $results = test-connection $inputbox.Text -count $count | foreach { $outputBox.AppendText("Reply from $($_.ProtocolAddress): bytes=$($_.ReplySize) time=$($_.ResponseTime)ms TTL=$($_.TimeToLive)`r`n"); $_ }
    $summary = $results | measure-object -Property ResponseTime -Average -Minimum -Maximum
    $lost = $count - $summary.Count
    $percentLost = $lost * 100.0 / $count
    $outputBox.AppendText("Packets: Sent = $count, Received = $($summary.Count), Lost = $lost ($($percentLost)% loss)`r`n")
    $outputBox.AppendText("Minimum = $($summary.Minimum)ms, Maximum = $($summary.Maximum)ms, Average = $($summary.Average)ms`r`n")
}
```

**Edit**

Actually I stand corrected. Assigning the result to a variable (`$ping`) is causing powershell to wait for the output stream to be closed. You can easily do what you want, with `foreach-object`. Here I use a small helper function to clear the output box before writing the to the box:

```
function WriteEach-Object() { 
    param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [object[]]$inputs
    )  

    begin { $outputBox.Text = "" } 
    process { $inputs | foreach { $outputBox.AppendText($_) } } 
    end { $outputBox.AppendText("`r`n") } 
}

function fnping() {
    $outputBox.Text = "Please Wait..."
    ping $inputBox.Text | writeeach-object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add BEGIN {} PROCESS {} and END {} statements to control how your function works. If no such are given, Powershell assumes that everything is in the END {} statement, processing everything in one go.

Changing into this

```
Function FNPing {
  BEGIN {
  }

  PROCESS {
     $OutputBox.Text = "Please Wait..."
     $ping = ping ($InputBox.text)
     $OutputBox.Text = ""
     foreach ($line in $ping) {
         $OutputBox.Appendtext($line+[char]13+[char]10)
     }
  }

  END {
  }
}
```

should do the trick. Alternatively, you can replace `Function` with `Filter`, which assumes the code resides in the `PROCESS {}` block.

For more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx